# sort by values not present in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to sort objects, but i want this sorting to not be based on the direct value i have stored in the database.

In the database there are integer values, 1,2,3... but there is also a hash, that specifies, what those values mean.

```
{1 => "a", 2 => "za", 3 => "xa"}.
```

So if an instance has value 3, it should be sorted as "xa". Can I achieve this goal with `order()` method? It is important to not use arrays, but rather ActiveRecord Relations

Comment: Where and how is this hash stored?

Comment: static variable in the model

Comment: The only thing I can think now is using a temp table to store the number and text. Then join the tables by number and order by the text.

Comment: @Rafa Probably the best solution, but I would make a permanent table. This sounds like the type of data that should be in the database anyway.

Comment: so how do i make a temp table with this extra column filled with necessary values?

Answer (score 1):

For the making of a temp_table and populate it with the values of your hash, this should work.

```
sqlQuery1 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hash_tmp(id integer, hash_values integer)")
sqlQuery2 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(TRUNCATE hash_tmp)
Your_hash.each do |id, value| 
   sqlQuery3 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO hash_tmp(id, hash_values) VALUES (#{id}, '#{value}')")
end
```

You should have a model for that temp table you created, then you can get all the values (filtered or not) and order by the new field:

```
@YourTemp = Yourtemp_model.all(:order=> "hash_values")
```

This is assuming that to this point your hash holds all the possible values which means you can iterate it and populate your temp table with them.